# Marking a function `noexcept` that could cause an exception constructing the returned object

Tags: c++, exception, c++17, language-lawyer, c++20

Consider this function:

```cpp
std::vector<unsigned> copy(std::vector<unsigned> const& v) noexcept
{ return v; }

int main()
{
   try {
       (void)copy({1, 2, 3});
   } catch(...) {}
}
```

The construction by copy of the returned object could throw. In this case, would the exception be propagated to the caller (i.e. it's considered to happen in `main`) and thus would be handled in the `catch(...)` handler? Or would the exception run into `noexcept` and lead to invoking `std::terminate()`?

Have the changes about lifetimes rules in C++17/C++20 (standardized RVO, temporary materialization, implicit object creation, etc) changed some rules in this regard with respect to previous versions of the standard?

Comment: Copy constructor throwing calls `std::terminate` when returning from a noexcept function so it's probably not fine https://godbolt.org/z/seMbG1 (though this doesn't substitute for a quote from the standard)

Comment: What do you mean "is it legal"? Why would it not be legal?

Comment: @Barry wording improved.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

C++17 had a wording change that added sequencing around the return statement. The following paragraph was added.

> **[stmt.return]**
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.return#3) The copy-initialization of the result of the call is sequenced
> before the destruction of temporaries at the end of the
> full-expression established by the operand of the return statement,
> which, in turn, is sequenced before the destruction of local variables
> ([stmt.jump]) of the block enclosing the return statement.

The result object is initialized before that local variables in scope are destroyed. This means the throw is in the scope of the function. So, any exception thrown at this point is not on the caller side.

As such, marking the function as `noexcept` is gonna make the program terminate.

RVO doesn't change that. It only affects at what storage the result object is initialized in, but the initialization itself is still part of the function's execution.

Comment: I'm also fairly certain all of this was also the intended behavior prior to C++17, where the wording made it clearer. I can't find where I read that intention originally, however.

Comment: +1 For the return statement sequence I was too lazy to find and cite from the standard. The better  and correct answer.

Comment: I generally agree with virtually everything in this answer. However, RVO does help to some degree, because if it might avoid any copy construction in the first place. Though that is not the case for the code in question...

Answer (score 4):

> In this case, would the exception be propagated to the caller (i.e. it's considered to happen in main) and thus would be handled in the catch(...) handler?

I disagree. The copy must be done in the function scope as part of the return statement expression. Because local destructors are called only after return and they are definetely in the function scope.

Yes, C++17 made some guarantees about RVO, in particular this example is now guaranteed elision:

```cpp
struct Foo{};

Foo bar(){
    Foo local;
    return Foo{};
    // Foo:~Foo(local);
}

Foo var = bar();
```

Still, if `Foo:Foo()` throws, the function is not noexcept. All RVO says that there is no move nor copy into `var` variable and `Foo{}` expression constructs the object at the location `var`. Yet it does not change when the object is constructed - in the function scope, before the destructors are even called.

Furthermore, mandatory RVO does not apply here since `v` is not a prvalue but l-value.

Comment: I have edited your answer because I change the wording of my question; so I edited yours to match. I hope it's ok to you.

Comment: Barry edited my question so I edited your answer in turn again haha